# Generic `erase_if` method for container types

Tags: c++, c++14, template-meta-programming

I'm trying to write a generic `erase_if` method that can be used on any container type to remove elements given a predicate. It should either use the erase-remove-idiom if the container allows it, or loop through the container and call the `erase` method. I also just want to provide the container itself, not the `begin` and `end` iterator separatly. That shall be handled by the method.

However I can't get the meta-template to work to distinguish between the two cases through SFINAE. I'm trying to check whether the method `std::remove_if` (or `std::remove`) would be well defined for a given type, but the value is either `true` for both `vector` and `map` (in which case the code won't compile) or `false` for both of them. I'm quite new to template meta-programming, so is there something I'm missing? Or maybe there's another, better solution?

Below is my example code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <map>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>


namespace my_std
{
    using std::begin;
    using std::end;

    namespace detail
    {
        template <typename T>
        // this is false for both vector and map
        auto is_remove_compatible(int) -> decltype(std::remove_if(begin(std::declval<T&>()), end(std::declval<T&>()),
                                                                  [](auto&&) { return false; }),
                                                   std::true_type{});

        // this is true for both vector and map
        // auto is_remove_compatible(int)
        //  -> decltype(std::remove(begin(std::declval<T&>()), end(std::declval<T&>()), std::declval<T::value_type&>()),
        //              std::true_type{});

        template <typename T>
        auto is_remove_compatible(...) -> std::false_type;
    }

    template <typename T>
    using is_remove_compatible = decltype(detail::is_remove_compatible<T>(0));

    template <typename T>
    constexpr bool is_remove_compatible_v = is_remove_compatible<T>::value;

    template <typename Cont, typename Pred>
    std::enable_if_t<is_remove_compatible_v<Cont>> erase_if(Cont& container, Pred pred)
    {
        std::cout << "Using erase-remove\n";
        container.erase(std::remove_if(begin(container), end(container), pred), end(container));
    }

    template <typename Cont, typename Pred>
    std::enable_if_t<!is_remove_compatible_v<Cont>> erase_if(Cont& container, Pred pred)
    {
        std::cout << "Using loop\n";
        for (auto it = begin(container); it != end(container);)
        {
            if (pred(*it))
                it = container.erase(it);
            else
                ++it;
        }
    }
}

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, std::vector<T> const& v)
{
    if (!v.empty())
    {
        out << '[';
        std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<T>(out, ", "));
        out << "\b\b]";
    }
    return out;
}

template <typename K, typename V>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, std::map<K, V> const& v)
{
    out << '[';
    for (auto const& p : v)
        out << '{' << p.first << ", " << p.second << "}, ";
    out << "\b\b]";
    return out;
}

int main(int argc, int argv[])
{
    auto vp = my_std::is_remove_compatible_v<std::vector<int>>;
    auto mp = my_std::is_remove_compatible_v<std::map<int, int>>;

    std::cout << vp << ' ' << mp << '\n';

    std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    auto v2 = v;
    my_std::erase_if(v2, [](auto&& x) { return x % 2 == 0; });

    std::map<int, int> m{{1, 0}, {2, 0}, {3, 0}, {4, 0}, {5, 0}};
    auto m2 = m;
    my_std::erase_if(m2, [](auto&& x) { return x.first % 2 == 0; });

    std::cout << v << " || " << v2 << '\n';
    std::cout << m << " || " << m2 << '\n';

    std::cin.ignore();
}
```

Comment: [Off Topic] If you wan't it to work with all standard containers then you need a special overload for `std::forward_list` as that doesn't have `erase`.  Instead it has `erase_after`.

Comment: The methods used are not SFINAE friendly :-(, but raise hard error.

Comment: Easier to (partial) specialize `is_remove_compatible<container<T>>` directly for the different supported container.

Comment: What compiler are you using? gcc & clang fail to compile your example because of the use of a lambda in the `decltype` expression and `int argv[]`. Anyway, there aren't too many containers in the std lib, so you could just create an `erase_if` overload for each.

Comment: @Praetorian I'm using VC2015, where it compiles fine. I don't wont to create overloads for each container type, because I also want it to work for custom containers not part of the std lib.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This idea is wrong for two reasons:

```
auto is_remove_compatible(int) -> decltype(std::remove_if(begin(std::declval<T&>()), end(std::declval<T&>()),
                                                          [](auto&&) { return false; }),
                                           std::true_type{});
```

First, you can't have a lambda in an unevaluated context, so the code is ill-formed. Second, even if it wasn't ill-formed (which is easy to fix), `remove_if()` isn't SFINAE-friendly on anything. If you pass in something that isn't a predicate to `remove_if`, or a non-modifiable iterator, that's not required by the standard to be anything but a hard error.

The way I would do it right now is via the chooser idiom. Basically, have conditional sfinae based on a rank ordering:

```
template <std::size_t I> struct chooser : chooser<I-1> { };
template <> struct chooser<0> { };

template <class Cont, class Predicate>
void erase_if(Cont& container, Predicate&& predicate) {
    return erase_if_impl(container, std::forward<Predicate>(predicate), chooser<10>{});
}
```

And then we just have our various `erase_if_impl` conditions, in order:

```
// for std::list/std::forward_list
template <class Cont, class Predicate>
auto erase_if_impl(Cont& c, Predicate&& predicate, chooser<3> )
    -> decltype(void(c.remove_if(std::forward<Predicate>(predicate))))
{
    c.remove_if(std::forward<Predicate>(predicate));
}

// for the associative containers (set, map, ... )
template <class Cont, class Predicate>
auto erase_if_impl(Cont& c, Predicate&& predicate, chooser<2> )
    -> decltype(void(c.find(std::declval<typename Cont::key_type const&>())))
{
    using std::begin; using std::end;
    for (auto it = begin(c); it != end(c); )
    {
        if (predicate(*it)) {
            it = c.erase(it);
        } else {
            ++it;
        }
    }
}

// for everything else, there's MasterCard
template <class Cont, class Predicate>
void erase_if_impl(Cont& c, Predicate&& predicate, chooser<1> )
{
    using std::begin; using std::end;
    c.erase(std::remove_if(begin(c), end(c), std::forward<Predicate>(predicate)), end(c));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't quite understand the syntax `decltype(void(c.remove_if(std::forward<Predicate>(predicate)))`. What exactly does `void(...)` mean in this context?

Comment: @SebastianStern He's casting the return type to `void`, otherwise the return type of `erase_if_impl` would be the same as that of `c.remove_if`